# Вернуть рамку в KDE Plasma

Tags: kde

В приложении нажал на верхнюю часть рамки правой кнопкой мыши, выбрал "Дополнительно" - "Без рамки".
Как теперь вернуть рамку?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я тут подумал, а это вообще нормальный вопрос для стаковерфлоу? Ну в целом KDE связан с линуксом, а вопросы с линуксом - это норм.

Comment: Проблема решилась перезапуском приложения. Буду признателен, если кто-то подскажет другие способы.

Comment: В теории этот вопрос должен быть на "Unix & Linux" ветке, но для ру сегмента ветку не завезли, так что вопрос уместен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Комбинация клавиш `Alt+F3` открывает меню, позволяющее снова включить рамку.